# Is there a simple way to compute the Jacobian of the following function? (from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose I have a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ whose entries $A_{i,j}(x,y)$ are differentiable functions from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Consider the function $F$ from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$obtained by $A\cdot (x,y)^t$.

Is there an easy way to compute the Jacobian of $F$ in terms of $A$?
I couldn't quite make the chain rule work... Any comments and suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: the dimensions do not work out, if each entry has outputs in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the matrix $A$ has dimension 8, and $F$ should be mapping from $\mathbb{R}^8$ to itself

Comment: @qbert sorry typo fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way around applying the product rule in a correct way. You have
$$y=A(x).x\ ,$$
which expands into
$$y_i=\sum_{k=1}^2 A_{ik}(x)x_k\qquad(1\leq i\leq 2)\ .$$
It follows that
$${\partial y_i\over\partial x_l}=\sum_{k=1}^2A_{ik.l}(x)x_k +A_{il}\qquad(1\leq i\leq2, \ 1\leq l\leq 2)\ .$$
Now compute
$$J_F(x)={\partial y_1\over\partial x_2}-{\partial y_2\over\partial x_1}\ .$$
The Jacobian $J_F(x)$ will be a function of $x=(x_1,x_2)$ depending in a quite arbitrary way on $x$, as is the matrix $A$.

Comment: it is not $y=F$ here? That is $F=A(x)\cdot x$ for $x=(x_1,x_2)$.

Comment: @Masacroso: $y$ is the variable for points in the image plane, whereas $F$ is the name of the map.